# roi des passes - meaning

Tags: sens

In the TV series "Marseille", I heard the following dialogue between a reporter and the Marseille mayor at the haftime of a soccer game in a stadium:

- Reporter: L'OM gagne, Mr le Maire, c'est bon pour la mairie?
- Mayor: Vous avez toujours été le roi des passes. Merci quand même.

What does "roi des passes" mean in this context? Smartass? Quick-witted?

Comment: *Une passe* is a sports term : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passe. (6). https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passe. https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/passe

Comment: A "passe" is also an instance of a prostitute doing their job. I don't know the series but it might be that meaning implied here...

Comment: @LaurentS. If there's a double-entendre, which is possible but we lack context, it is not with the meaning you mention but with the use as a synonym of "manipulation" (no disrespect to people from Marseilles meant of course). Soccer being mentioned in the context the act of moving the ball to another player is clearly in the picture.

Comment: As they are in a OM game in a soccer stadium, the soccer reference seems clear to me. I'm just not sure what it means. I guess that the mayor meant that the reporter, similar to the soccer play who thinks fast and it is skillful with the ball to do precise and quick passes, is quick-witted and skillful with the words, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is clearly a sports metaphor: the word *passe* means the action of passing the ball in football/soccer, so it makes sense to make an allusion to it when commenting a football match.

There are numerous crude jokes in French about the double-meaning of *passe* (which can also be an act of sexual intercourse with a prostitute), but that does not seem to be the case here.

If we follow the logic of a football metaphor,  the journalist is *le roi des passes* because he is good at asking sharp questions that the interviewee can use to their own benefit, if they answer with a witty retort - just like a football striker will put themselves in the spotlight if they score a goal after a good assist (= *passe décisive*) from a team mate.

The answer "merci quand même" may seem a bit contradictory, but may just mean that the mayor acknowledges the journalist's wit but refuses to play along.